# How can I implement confidence level in a CNN with tensorflow?

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

My CNN outputs an array of values that I have to check for the biggest one and take it as the predicted class. Example:

```
-148.7290802 , -133.90687561,  -90.850914  , -135.78356934,
    -128.6325531 , -125.76812744,  -85.41909027,  -72.3269577 ,
    -103.51300812
```

For class index 6.

Now, how can I get the confidence of that result?

My setup is:

```
predict_op = [tf.argmax(py_x,1), py_x]
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(py_x, Y))
train_op = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learningRate, decayRate).minimize(cost)
```

Updated code now returning: [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]]

```
predict_op = tf.nn.softmax(py_x)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(py_x, Y))
train_op = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learningRate, decayRate).minimize(cost)
```

Comment: Your return value is what you assign to **train_op**?

Comment: No, train_op is the tensor for the training. The expected return value is in Y. For the test prediction i'm evaluating predict_op that returns the value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apply **softmax** in the last stage; this will yield posterior probabilities at the final stage.  You're already using softmax in the set-up; just use it on the final vector to convert it to RMS probabilities.  The *confidence* of that prediction is simply the probability of the top item.

For a quick illustration, see the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) under *Generalization and Statistics*.  This section also describes the confidence of the model overall.

Comment: Don't I need the output value for the softmax?

Comment: After applying softmax i'm getting [[ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]]
Should't it be between 0-1?

Comment: I'm perplexed by this: you applied SoftMax in place of your previous evaluation, and now you have 13 values instead of 9 ???

Comment: Sorry, I've changed the dataset for testing purposes. It was returning the same as before but with 13 now.

Comment: Is there a way to get actual float values instead of just 1 and zeroes?\

Comment: You *have* float values ... but SoftMax appears to be absolutely confident in the prediction.  This is not what I expected to see.  Can you update the code in your question, please?  I have to check out for the night now, but I'd like to see it in the morning ... and maybe someone else will find it before I do.

Comment: I have updated the code. I don't think it is that confident since it does not predict correctly for some of them

Comment: I got the desired results by changing my code from
`self.prediction_op = tf.argmax(y_conv, 1)`
to
`self.prediction_op = tf.nn.softmax(y_conv)`

Comment: Thanks for supplying the specific solution, and for properly retiring the question.

Answer (score 4):

[Yarin Gal disagrees with the accepted answer](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/yarin/blog_3d801aa532c1ce.html): "by the way, using softmax to get probabilities is actually not enough to obtain model uncertainty" "This is because the standard model would pass the predictive mean through the softmax rather than the entire distribution.", and he offers an example to make this clear: "If you give me several pictures of cats and dogs – and then you ask me to classify a new cat photo – I should return a prediction with rather high confidence. But if you give me a photo of an ostrich and force my hand to decide if it's a cat or a dog – I better return a prediction with very low confidence."

[He suggests](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/yarin/blog_3d801aa532c1ce.html) a dropout-based method wherein at query time you feedforward several times with random dropout and observe the scatter of the answers. I highly recommend reading [the blog post](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/yarin/blog_3d801aa532c1ce.html) to get a rigorous treatment of uncertainty in general and in deep nets in particular.

Unfortunately I am not yet enough of a TensorFlow ninja to know exactly how to implement this and give some clever code off the top of my head.